# How to prevent WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer to stop playing music when the computer is sleeping?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, alarm, wakeup

I wrote a Winforms app that alarms for certain events by playing sounds using the WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer. But the issue is, when the system is sleeping, it doesn't play anything.

As soon as I press some buttons on the keyboard where you see the windows fingerprint/PIN screen, the sound starts playing, if an alarm event is active.

How can I make it so that it plays the sounds regardless of the system sleeping state.

Do I have to wake the computer in code in such cases? If so, how?

Comment: If a system plays sound when it's sleeping then it's no more sleeping.

Comment: The only way to stop this is to disable sleep mode.  By definition if your computer goes to sleep then windows will stop your programs from running! see here: https://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Windows-10-from-Going-to-Sleep

Comment: In addition to OS and hardware, the software also should support [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to be able to keep playing sound on modern standby. Have you checked to see whether the Windows Media Player supports modern standby? Open WMP, play a music and let it go to standby, if it continues playing it means WMP (and WMP active-x) supports modern standby, otherwise it means WMP (and WMP active-x) doesn't support modern standby.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I will check this

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure, but it looks like you can create a timer, which will wake up the system in desired moment. Then you will able to play your sound as usual.
The idea is a following:

- create a waitable timer with `CreateWaitableTimerW`
- set the timer to a desired time with `SetWaitableTimer`, passing `fResume=TRUE`
- wait for the timer with `WaitForSingleObject`
- play your sound as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) function.

**SetThreadExecutionState**. Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.

- Display is OFF but the system is active.

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState.ES_CONTINUOUS | ExecutionState.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED );
```

- Display is allways ON

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState.ES_CONTINUOUS | ExecutionState.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | ExecutionState.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED);
```

---

In this example every 30 seconds, the program calls SetThreadExecutionState function.

You can check/download this code on https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/PreventWmplayerStopWhenSleep

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PreventSleep
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        const int REFRESH_MILLISECONDS = 30000;//Change this value. 30000ms = 30s.

        [Flags]
        public enum ExecutionState : uint 
        {
            ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
        }

        
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
        static extern ExecutionState SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState esFlags);



        Stopwatch stopwatch;
        private Timer timerRefresh;

        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Music.mp3";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";

            timerRefresh = new Timer();
            timerRefresh.Enabled = true;
            timerRefresh.Interval = 1000;
            timerRefresh.Tick += new EventHandler(this.timerRefresh_Tick);
        }

        private void timerRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / REFRESH_MILLISECONDS) == 1 )
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState.ES_CONTINUOUS | ExecutionState.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED ); //Display is OFF but the system is active.
                //SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState.ES_CONTINUOUS | ExecutionState.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | ExecutionState.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED); //Display is allways ON.
            }
        }

        private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
            SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState.ES_CONTINUOUS);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Settings**
[image]